# What is the use of the first argument to Django's patterns method?

Tags: python, django

What is the significance of the first argument (containing `''` in the example below) to [`patterns`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#patterns)?

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^articles/2003/$', 'news.views.special_case_2003'),
    (r'^articles/(\d{4})/$', 'news.views.year_archive'),
)
```

Sometimes I've seen it filled in, like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    'zinnia.views.entries',
    url(r'^$',
        'entry_index', entry_conf_index,
        name='zinnia_entry_archive_index'),
    )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a prefix to the view paths. See the [documentation for `patterns`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#the-view-prefix).

The equivalent of your first example using this argument is:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('news.views',
    (r'^articles/2003/$', 'special_case_2003'),
    (r'^articles/(\d{4})/$', 'year_archive'),
)
```

The equivalent of your second example with the first argument set to `''` is:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',
        'zinnia.views.entries.entry_index', entry_conf_index,
        name='zinnia_entry_archive_index'),
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

it is a prefix for all the urls, for example you can add `news.views` in your case:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('news.views',
    (r'^articles/2003/$', 'special_case_2003'),
    (r'^articles/(\d{4})/$', 'nyear_archive'),
)
```